# Rails SSO from Wordpress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, single-sign-on

I wanted to provide SSO from my wordpress to a Rails App (using devise). The idea is add a link on wordpress to the rails app and the user automatically will login if they are already logged in on wordpress. What's the best way to reach this goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since version 1.2 `Devise` supports Omniauth, check out their Wiki entry [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) for a tutorial using Fb as a strategy provider. I imagine Wordpress integration should be similar but I havent tried integrating Wordpress and see that in the Omniauth Wiki there is not a entry for Wordpress strategy, but may be this gem can help. http://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-wordpress

Comment: This integration worked fine using the wordpress.com site. That I'm trying to do is the same with a hosted wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this gem](https://github.com/jwickard/omniauth-wordpress-oauth2-plugin) There is also a writeup on configuring both the wordpress provider and rails applications http://www.objectpartners.com/2014/02/18/single-sign-on-with-rails-wordpress-and-oauth2/